# How to get model Default values into Django Form so that is_valid returns True

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django modelForm that excludes some model fields so that when it is used on a web page, those fields are available.  I'd like to use the same modelForm object on an API.

When I use the form on a webpage, the rendering of the form takes into account the default values of the model Field, the form is rendered and the submitted "final" form contains those values.  Similarly I can do the same thing with an initial dict passed to the form during creation.

Problem is, when you expose a modelForm via an API there is no initial rendering of the default values to cause them to show up in the final submitted form.  What this results in is `is_valid` returning false because the form "requires" fields that would have been filled in with their default values via the initial rendering of the form.

Is there some setting to make the form look at these "default" model values when validating, or do I just have to write validation code to take them into account?  Since the model specifies the default values, it seems like this should just work, but it doesn't.

Barring that, how do I find the fields to pull the default values from them as the point I'm validating the form.  So far I can find the methods I wrote and the methods contributed to the class such as `get_completion_format_display` but I don't see the definition of the fields in the model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've come up with this (that works), but I'm hoping someone else has a more elegant solution.  This does exactly what I need it to do, and while debugging thru Django, I don't see any other way to do this at all.  The instance parameter is merged with initial data before it is used, so that proved to be a fruitless way to "fix" this.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Demonstrates using the default values from the data model so that form.is_valid() 
    will return True if the form has sufficient data (useful when using a form object with an api."""

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('status', 'uuid', 'submitted_on', 'completed_on', 
                   'last_attempt', 'failure_reason')

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Grab the default values from the model and add them to the form so it will validate """
        if data:
            for field in self.Meta.model._meta.fields:
                if (field.default != NOT_PROVIDED 
                    and field.name not in self.Meta.exclude 
                    and field.name not in data:
                    data[field.name] = field.default
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data, files, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question 100% but what about customizing the form and changing the fields you want to exclude to HiddenFields with initial values? Then they will validate while not being visible

Comment: This is used in a RESTFUL API.  There are no hidden fields.  Another program fills out the fields it wants to submit and sends them.  This same form is used on a webpage.  The view code is the same too (with an api=True/False argument).

Comment: Thanks for this code, very useful. I think Django relies too much on form validation instead of model validation, which is painful when data is manipulated automatically in many different places, and not only in user interfaces, and still needs to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I decided to solve it at a model level:

```
class DefaultingModelMetaClass(models.Model.__metaclass__):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        obj = super(DefaultingModelMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        for f in obj._meta.fields:
            if not hasattr(f, 'orig_blank'):
                f.orig_blank = f.blank
            if f.has_default():
                # If a default value is provided we allow blank values for the field (not-required field)
                # We fill it with the default value when saved if it is still blank
                f.blank = True

        return obj

class DefaultingModel(models.Model):
    """
    Model class which makes fields not-required if they are providing a default value.
    Also fills in empty values for fields with default values on save.
    """

    __metaclass__ = DefaultingModelMetaClass

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for f in self._meta.fields:
            if f.orig_blank:
                # We do not do anything with fields originally allowing blank values
                continue

            raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
            if f.has_default() and raw_value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                setattr(self, f.attname, f.get_default())

        super(DefaultingModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```